# × Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component

Tags: reactjs, jsx, react-big-calendar

I have a weekly calendar, where to use the react-big-calendar.
In this library, there is an action called `onSelectEvent` where when I click on an event, it reproduces an action. But when I click on the component to perform the action, it points out the error.

In the library's own documentation, it thus uses `onSelectEvent = {event => alert (event.title)}`
So it works perfectly however, when I switch to `onSelectEvent = {event => modal()}` or `onSelectEvent = {modal()}`
he points out this error:

```
Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
```

My code:

```
import Modal from "../modal";

return (
  <div>
    <Calendar
      events={events}
      localizer={localizer}
      defaultView={Views.WEEK}
      defaultDate={new Date(programming[0].schedules[0].initial_date)}
      onSelectEvent={event => Modal()}
      views={{ month: true, week: MyWeek }}
      toolbar={false}
      style={{ height: "70vw", paddingTop: 35 }}
    />
  </div>
);
```

Code Modal:

```
return (
  <div>
    <Button id="Popover1" type="button">
      Launch Popover
    </Button>
    <Popover
      placement="bottom"
      isOpen={popoverOpen}
      target="Popover1"
      toggle={toggle}
    >
      <PopoverHeader>Popover Title</PopoverHeader>
      <PopoverBody>
        Sed posuere consectetur est at lobortis. Aenean eu leo quam.
        Pellentesque ornare sem lacinia quam venenatis vestibulum.
      </PopoverBody>
    </Popover>
  </div>
);
```

Comment: Is Modal a component or a function?

Comment: is a component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Modal is a component, you cannot call it as a function. Instead you need to render it. To render the modal you can keep a state which you set to know when to trigger it

```
import Modal from "../modal";
const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
return (
  <div>
    {isOpen && <Modal /> }
    <Calendar
      events={events}
      localizer={localizer}
      defaultView={Views.WEEK}
      defaultDate={new Date(programming[0].schedules[0].initial_date)}
      onSelectEvent={event => setIsOpen(true)}
      views={{ month: true, week: MyWeek }}
      toolbar={false}
      style={{ height: "70vw", paddingTop: 35 }}
    />
  </div>
);
```

To close the modal, you will need to set the state to false.